# LINQ trying to get database records error Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL

Tags: linq

I am trying to get companies by their 3 digit asx code, I am passing space seperatd asx codes and want all companies with those code returned.

```
List<CompanyProfile> companies = null;
        try
        {
            using (var context = GetDataContext())
            {
                companies = context.CompanyProfiles.Where(x => spacesSeperatedCodes.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Any(y => string.Compare(x.ASXCode, y, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0 && x.dtRetired == null)).ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error in GetCompaniesByLetter", ex);
        }
        return companies;
```

error I am getting is

Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just follow the suggestion generated by the error. You could do something like this, anyway :

```
        List<CompanyProfile> companies = null;
        try
        {
            var codes = spacesSeperatedCodes.Split(" ".ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            using (var context = GetDataContext())
            {
                companies = context.CompanyProfiles.Where(x => codes.Contains(x.CustomerID) && x.dtRetired == null).ToList();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error in GetCompaniesByLetter", ex);
        }
        return companies;
```

I hope the result is really what you've been looking for. If it's not, just tell me, OK. Maybe I've missed something here.